EventHub spark structured streaming using certificate authentication
I want to use structured streaming for EventHub message consumption using pyspark in Azure Synapse and I was pointed to this project https://github.com/alexott/databricks-playground/tree/main/kafka-eventhubs-aad-auth. Could someone guide me if this could be modified to use certificate instead of secret authentication?, I tried to modify the ServicePrincipalCredentialsAuth class shown below to use ClientCredentialFactory.createFromCertificate but I am not able to make it work.
package net.alexott.demos.eventhubs_aad;

import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ClientCredentialFactory;
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ConfidentialClientApplication;
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.IClientCredential;


import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import scala.collection.immutable.Map;

public class ServicePrincipalCredentialsAuth extends ServicePrincipalAuthBase {
    private final String clientSecret;

    private static final String AAD_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY = "aad_client_secret";

    public ServicePrincipalCredentialsAuth(Map<String, String> params) {
        super(params);
        clientSecret = params.get(AAD_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY).get();
    }

    @Override
    ConfidentialClientApplication getClient() throws MalformedURLException {
        IClientCredential credential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(this.clientSecret);
        return ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(this.clientId, credential)
            .authority(this.authEndpoint)
            .build();
    }

}


Setup Azure EventHub with AAD and Certificate Authentication:
Register an Azure AD application and configure it for certificate authentication.
Upload your public key to the Azure AD application.
Assign the necessary roles to the application in Azure EventHub.Create a self-signed certificate and export it in PFX format.
Upload the certificate to Azure Key Vault and create a linked service in Azure Synapse.Use mssparkutils to access the certificate from Azure Key Vault.Configure Spark settings to use certificate-based authentication.

To modify the Java code for EventHub Spark Structured Streaming using certificate authentication instead of a client secret, you need to adjust the ServicePrincipalCredentialsAuth class to use ClientCredentialFactory.createFromCertificate instead of ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret. Below is the modified Java code that incorporates certificate authentication:
ServicePrincipalCredentialsAuth Class:


public class ServicePrincipalCredentialsAuth extends ServicePrincipalAuthBase {
    private final String certificatePath;
    private final String certificatePassword;

    private static final String AAD_CERTIFICATE_PATH_KEY = "aad_certificate_path";
    private static final String AAD_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD_KEY = "aad_certificate_password";

    public ServicePrincipalCredentialsAuth(Map<String, String> params) {
        super(params);
        certificatePath = params.get(AAD_CERTIFICATE_PATH_KEY).get();
        certificatePassword = params.get(AAD_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD_KEY).get();
    }

    @Override
    ConfidentialClientApplication getClient() throws MalformedURLException {
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(certificatePath);
            keyStore.load(stream, certificatePassword.toCharArray());
            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(keyStore.aliases().nextElement(), certificatePassword.toCharArray());
            X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(keyStore.aliases().nextElement());
            IClientCredential credential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromCertificate(privateKey, certificate);
            return ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(this.clientId, credential)
                    .authority(this.authEndpoint)
                    .build();
        } catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException ex) {
            throw new MalformedURLException("Failed to load certificate: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}




To retrieve a secret stored in Azure Key Vault, refer to this GitHub
Azure Key Vault for fetching certificates using   Java:
   public ServicePrincipalCredentialsAuth(Map<String, String> params) {
        super(params);
        this.keyVaultUrl = params.get(AAD_KEYVAULT_URL_KEY);
        this.clientId = params.get(AAD_CLIENT_ID_KEY);
        this.clientSecret = params.get(AAD_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY);
        this.certificateName = params.get(AAD_CERTIFICATE_NAME_KEY);
    }

    @Override
    ConfidentialClientApplication getClient() throws MalformedURLException {
        try {
           
            ClientCertificateCredential credential = new ClientCertificateCredentialBuilder()
                    .clientId(clientId)
                    .clientCertificate(getClientCertificate())
                    .vaultUrl(keyVaultUrl)
                    .build();

            CertificateClient certificateClient = new CertificateClientBuilder()
                    .credential(credential)
                    .vaultUrl(keyVaultUrl)
                    .buildClient();

            CertificateWithPolicy certificateWithPolicy = certificateClient.getCertificate(certificateName);

            X509Certificate certificate = certificateWithPolicy.getCertificate();

          
            IClientCredential msalCredential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromCertificate(certificate.getPublicKey(), certificate);



Refer   to this link for  Azure key vault instance in Azure Synapse.

